# mongodb backup role - mongodump

Tags: mongodb, authentication, database-backups

We have a development team that will periodically take a mongodump out of DEV and then restore it back to their local host for work.  We have recently implemented authentication in mongodb and i would like to be able to allow our development team do a mongodump on one DB only so they can restore it to their local host.

I have a role that inherits the backup role from Admin, but that is for our DBA to backup the whole system.

My question, how do I allow for this backup role to be used by a specific user (lets call them "webdev") for a specific DB (lets call it "products")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an user in the `products` database with read permissions:

```
> use products
> db.createUser(  {
 user: "webdev",
 pwd: "password",
 roles: [ "read" ]
 } )
```

Just remember to call mongodump with `--excludeCollectionsWithPrefix=system`

```
mongodump --excludeCollectionsWithPrefix=system
```

In order to avoid permission errors (assuming you are using Mongo 3)

Comment: That was the exact answer!  Thank you very much anresk

Answer (score 0):

I am using MongoDB3.4 version, First of all you want one root access for admin database and connect mongo shell,

> $ mongo -u username -p xxxxxx --authenticationDatabase admin

After connecting mongoshell, change the database,

```
use products
```

After change the DB create the new user,

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "webdev",
    pwd: "xxxxx",
    roles: [
       { role: "read", db: "products" },
       { role: "backup", db: "products"}
    ]
  }
)
```

Above I mentioned, **webdev** user can be able to read the all collections and take backup access also.

```
db.auth('webdev', 'xxxxx')
```

after successfully authenticate, you can able to read and take backup from **DEV server**.

Below I mentioned mongodump query with new *webdev* user.

```
mongodump --host hostname --port 27017 --username webdev --password xxxxx --authenticationDatabase products --db products --collection collection_name --out mongodump_outpath
```

Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#backup

Note:

1. Don't take mongodump frequently in production. It will impacts the
   performance issue.
2. Don't give backup and restore access to any other teams like developer, 
   tester,..etc
3. Admin or DBA only do every time Backup/Restore.

   Thank You. Please revert for any concern.

Comment: @UpTheCreek,  Before going to take backup if you need to check DBs or collections or reading some specific datas  ....etc